# IOS Swift - Can't retrive person note from addressbook

Tags: ios, swift, addressbook

Any one have any suggestions why i can get firstName, lastname and birthday, However i can't retrieved the notes filed from iphone address book ?

**Preprations**

- Address book access is granted
- Person added in address book with all fields including note

**Current Results**

nil for note only, all other fields retrieved correctly

**Sample code used**

```
var firstName: String = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as NSString
var lastName: String = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let birthday = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonBirthdayProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as NSDate?
let notes    = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonNoteProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as NSString?
```

Comment: I ran into a very similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953078/unable-to-access-kabpersonnoteproperty/29958195). @matt reasoned that asking for permissions got around a bug in copying the address book data by accessing the original rather than the copy. Were you able to resolve this? What are your thoughts on the linked solution?